# Add ASP.NET MVC Routed URLs to view-model objects (for use in JSON)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'm writing an application which uses ASP.NET MVC with JSON.NET as the server, sending JSON to the client which is read by Knockout and then displayed with data-bindings. This is all working wonderfully, except for one problem:

I have a class `Customer` which is used to generate a `ReviewAuthorViewModel` class - the latter is meant specifically for JSON serialization and removes unnecessary fields, circular references, etc. On the client, I want to render a link to the Customer's profile page, with the URL coming from a defined MVC route "user/{username}". Because I'm sending this via JSON, I don't have a `.cshtml` page in which I can call `Url.Action`.

**The question is:** For an arbitrary object, how do I most efficiently/elegantly get a URL for an action with some data, without a .cshtml view?

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require extra code in each action, but that may be the only choice apart from recreating the routing tables client-side in JavaScript. Below are the things I've already tried, and what was unsatisfactory with each.

**Solution Attempt 1**

Call the `UrlHelper.Action` method in the `ReviewAuthorViewModel` class. However, the `UrlHelper` requires a request context. For the sake of separation of concerns, I don't want my view model to have a dependency on `System.Web.Routing`, nor do I want it to need a request context to function.

**Solution Attempt 2**

Create a class `RouteInformation` with members Controller, Action, and Data, and an interface `IUrlViewModel` with two properties, a get of type `RouteInformation` and a get/set string named `Url`. The view models needing links then implement this interface, and controllers look for view models of type `IUrlViewModel` and run `UrlHelper.Action` with the information from the view model's `RouteInformation` instance, storing the result in the Url property.

This one *works* but without reflection I don't know how to find view models implementing `IUrlViewModel` within other view models, and it feels very kludgy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Attempt 1** is the OK solution. In asp.net-mvc, view models are part of presentation layer, designed specifically for use with views. You should not worry about having view model depend on asp.net specific things. In fact, they should be coupled, as they should be designed to maximize simplicity of view generation and data exchange between web server and web client. And it's good solution to create separate view model and not use `Customer` class directly for clients. It wouldn't have been OK if `Customer` was dependent on `Routing`.

In fact, you could set that property in controller -

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var viewModel = new ReviewAuthorViewModel();
        viewModel.ProfilePageUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Profile");

        // return viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: What you suggest there is basically what I did in solution 2, abstracted to an interface to make it more readily reusable. However, that makes it hard to get a hold of nested view model objects which should have URLs added, and has to be added to every action, which seems like a good way to introduce elusive errors.

Comment: I feel second solution is way too complicated and over engineered.